# Ignore index when reading csv file to jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I managed to import csv file to jupyter. However, I would like to ignore the index column which is automatically generated when the dataframe is being shown on the jupyter.

**Below is my code:**

```
raw = pd.read_csv(r'''CI.csv ''',index_col=None)
store=raw
store
```

**Result:**

```
  _____Case______Children____Income($10K)____
   0     1         2           3
   1     2         5           4
   2     3         1           9
```

I would like the result to show only Case, Children and Income while ignoring the 1st column which is the automatically generated index.

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv(r'''CI.csv ''',index_col=[0])`